# Implementation of double way initialization of class objects in C++

Tags: c++, qt, api-design

I was going through the Qt API when I suddenly noticed some functions that allow the user to initialize the class objects in 2 ways. For example:
The QReqExp class:
It can be initialized in one go like this:

```
QRegExp regExp("*.wk?", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);
```

Or it can be initialized step by step like this:

```
QRegExp regExp;
regExp.setPattern("*.wk?");
regExp.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
regExp.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
```

I want to know how is this system implemented?? I mean are the properties of the class object set to default values until the user explicitly sets them?

Comment: https://code.woboq.org/kde/include/qt4/QtCore/qregexp.h.html - convenient code browser, you can click on objects to go to their implementations and trace the implemetnation.

Comment: there can be constructor with no argument & constructor with number of argument in C++. so you can create object with no argument or with arguments. in no arguments you are going to set parameters with external call to API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QRegExp regExp("*.wk?", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);
```

With the above statement an object is created with one of the class constructors like below:-

```
  public:
    QRegExp(String param1, SomeType cs, SomeType wildcard)
    {
       this.param1 = param1;
       this.cs = cs;
       this.wildcard = wildcard;
     }
```

In the second case it is calling a default constructor and values are being setting with setter methods.

```
 QRegExp regExp;
```

The above statement will call a default constructor as below:-

```
 public:
   QRegExp():param1(some value),cs(some value),wildcard(some value)
   {
   }
```

class **QRegExp** also have following setter methods:-

```
 public:
    void setPattern(String String param1)
    {
        this.param = param1;
    }

 regExp.setPattern("*.wk?");// here you are calling the above method
```

For rest of the setter method just imagine they are also implemented like above.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at basic C++ for this.
The first statement `QRegExp regExp("*.wk?", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);` uses a [constructor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm) that takes the arguments and automatically initializes the class object's members with given arguments. The documentation for this particular constructor is given [here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#QRegExp-2).

The `QRegExp` class has overloaded constructors like most other classes in defined in the Qt Framework. This combines the concepts of constructors and Function Overloading.

In the second block of code, `QRegExp regExp;` initializes a `QRegExp` object without passing any arguments, all it is doing is allocating memory for all its members and is called **default constructor**. [This](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#QRegExp) is the constructor being called in this case.

After that you are calling specific set functions for each member in the class and initializing their values. Keep in mind these functions can be called in the first method too, to modify already assigned data. [`setPattern()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setCaseSensitivity), [`setCaseSensitivity()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setCaseSensitivity), and [`setPatternSyntax()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setPatternSyntax) are being used to specifically assign data to those particular members.